# update dotnet Package Id nonsense

Tags: linux, .net-framework

On Centos, I want to update `dotnet`. The `dotnet` output and [MSFT documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-update) do not help.

I have:

```
$ dotnet --version
3.1.408
```

```
 $ dotnet tool update -g 
Specify one tool Package Id to update.
Usage: dotnet tool update [options] <PACKAGE_ID>

Arguments:
  <PACKAGE_ID>   The NuGet Package Id of the tool to update.
```

```
$ dotnet tool list -g
Package Id      Version      Commands
-------------------------------------
```

Comment: [What have you tried other than `dotnet tool update -g`?  What version of CentOS.  CentOS 7 only supports up to .NET Core 6.0.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-centos)  You have to run two commands.  The first `sudo rpm -Uvh https://packages.microsoft.com/config/centos/7/packages-microsoft-prod.rpm` and then `sudo yum install dotnet-sdk-6.0`

Comment: Can you clarify the reason the MSFT documentation was not helpful?  Did you run either of the commands I suggested?  Can you clarify which version of CentOS you are using?  Please do not add the "Please Help" signature block back into your question, it's not necessary.

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

Comment: The MSFT documentation is not helpful because it's badly written and doesn't address my problem above.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the `rpm` and `yum` commands. Woops, I should not have written that because it's "not necessary". :-)

Comment: So I assume those commands resolved the issued?  I don't mind submitting an answer, although, I did get those commands from the documentation.